# How can I get dragged component info in vaadin7?

Tags: vaadin7

I'm using Vaadin7 Drag and Drop Events

Here is my code -

```
@Override
public void drop(DragAndDropEvent event) {
    Component sourceComponent = event.getTransferable()
            .getSourceComponent();
    if (sourceComponent instanceof BoardCard) {
        WrapperTargetDetails details = (WrapperTargetDetails) event
                .getTargetDetails();
        DropTarget target = details.getTarget();
        BoardCardVo sourceCard = ((BoardCard) sourceComponent).getBoardCardVo() ;

        if(target == sourceComponent){
            return ;
        }

        ...
    }
```

I thought, 'sourceComponent' was dragged-component, and 'target' was target component. However, these are the sameobject

How can I get component that was dragged?

(in gridlayout)

Comment: Hi , clarify on the data type/property of the component dragged in order to capture. You can also refer to this classic example Drag Components HTML5. https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/drag-drop/drag-components-html5